# How to pass a value from javascript to drupal 8 form?

Tags: javascript, drupal

I need to pass a value from Javascript to my drupal 8 form.

I've added a hidden field to the form. Javascript is calculating a value and writes it into the field. But how can I get to the value within the function submitForm()?

Is using a hidden field even the right approach? If so, what do I have to do, to make this work?

I've removed most of the code for readability.

FooForm.php:

```
class FooForm extends FormBase
{
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'fooID';
    }
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {

    //...here are lot's of elements not relevant right now

    $form['myhiddenfield'] = ['#type' => 'hidden'];//adding hidden field.
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'foo/foocalculator';

    return $form;
    }

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
    dpm($form_state->getValues()['myhiddenfield']);//not getting the calculated value.
    }
```

foocalculator.js:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
    passToDrupal = $('#myhiddenfield');
    $('#edit-submit--3').click(function (event) {
        calcRoute(address, $editparcel.fieldValue().toString())
    });
})(jQuery, Drupal);

function calcRoute(start, destination) {
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: destination,
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        mydistance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
        passToDrupal.val(mydistance);//adds value to hidden field.
    }    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hidden fields are a bit special because the changes of the field value are not directly visible among the submitted values (which can be retrieved with $form_state->getValues()). Instead, they are visible in the user input values of the form state, so try this:

```
$form_state->getUserInput()['myhiddenfield']
```

Be careful with using the getUserInput() for hidden fields, because unless you have a good reason why you do it (like you have in this case) a change in a hidden field is usually done by "unfriendly" entities, which are trying to break your site.

Comment: I spent the last couple hours playing around with storing the data in the _SESSION and in  \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore') and just wanted to give up. But this works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a default value to your hidden field:

```
$form['bid'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#default_value' => '');
```

Taken from:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#hidden

> Note that if you plan to use JavaScript to change your hidden element's value, you will need to use the #default_value property rather than #value.

I tested in Drupal 8, and it worked fine.